# How to control TLS version when WebAPI service accesses IdentityServer configuration on startup

Tags: tls1.2, identityserver3, bearer-token

I have an Authentication service built on Identity Server 3 and a set of WebAPI services using BearerTokenAuthentication. On startup, each of the WebAPI services makes a call to the Authentication service's .well-known/openid-configuration. That has been working fine until we recently configured the firewall between the WebAPI services and the Authentication service to only allow traffic with the TLS 1.2 protocol. Now the WebAPI services all fail to start and report that they cannot access the Authentication .well-known/openid-configuration because they "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel".

Update: The problem described is occurring in my Test environment and is eliminated when we modify the firewall to allow TLS 1.0. In my Dev and Staging environments, the firewall is configured to require TLS 1.2 and that configuration is *not* producing the above symptoms. Something else is different. I just haven't figured out yet what it is.

Based on this latest update, I have a different question. Any suggestions on what to look for in the server/environment that would cause the TLS 1.2 requirement not to work in one environment while working in the other two? I've started to look at the registry settings that control the server's use of SSL and TLS protocols, but haven't found a difference there when comparing a working server to the non-working one.

Final Update: I never did figure out what was different. Someone from the systems group rebuilt the Test server, which was exhibiting the problem, by cloning the Staging server, which was not exhibiting the problem. The rebuilt server handles TLS 1.2 just fine. So it was clearly something in the server, not the code. But that's about all we know.